# I can not see image although there is image control in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="imagesource" UriSource="pack://application:,,,/image/a.png" />
</Grid.Resources>
<Image x:Name="mImage" Source="{StaticResource imagesource}" Width="180" Height="180" />
```

I also tried this:

```
<Image x:Name="mImage" Source="a.png" Width="180" Height="180"/>
```

But it just shows an empty space.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to include "a.png" in your project and set its build action to Resource and then if your image is placed in "image" folder which is under application root folder, you can access the image as

```
<Image x:Name="mImage" Source="image/a.png" Width="180" Height="180"/>
```

Comment: sorry to late reply. in fact, i fount a solution before your answer, however, anyway, thanks.